# How to initialize an array using awk and bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to store values of the first line of a text file into an array. Here is what I have so far:

```
arr_values=()

awk '
    NR==1 {
            for (i=0; i<=NF; i++)
               'arr_values[i]'=$i
          }' file.txt

for ((i=0; i<${#arr_values[@]}; i++))
do
   echo arr_values[i]
done
```

I am getting an error with initializing the array mainly because I don't know how to use `awk` to initialize an external array. Any suggestions (only with `awk`)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
read -a array <<< $(head -n 1 file)

echo ${array[0]}
echo ${array[1]}
```

Comment: What is difference between my solution? Expect of process substitution which is not required here.

Comment: No seriously, your pipe starts a subshell which is ephemeral.

Comment: I am not sure what is really going on, but I know if I do `command | while read x; do array[0]=x; done` it never works as part of a pipe and the same thing is happening here.

Comment: You were right! It was a problem with my tests. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @hek2mgl Do you have any suggestions using `awk` because my bash script is filled with `awk` statements and I would like to keep it that way

Comment: You could replace `<<< $(head -n 1 file)` by `<<< $(awk 'NR==1 {print;exit}' file)`. Also dogbane's answer could be modified to use `awk` : `arr=($(awk 'NR==1{print;exit}' file))`. However, the `head` statement is perfect here.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can simply just do

```
read -ra arr_values < file.txt
```

Which would only process the first line and split it uniformly like `awk` does; saving it into `arr_values`. No need to fork with external binary commands.

Comment: why `\t`? The OP hasn't specified that and by default `awk` splits on whitespace.

Comment: @dogbane I don't always remember that. Just tested it and found out that I was wrong so I made the edit just some seconds before you made the comment.